# Globbing certain YYYYMMDD dates

Tags: bash, wildcard, glob

I'm trying to feed my perl script several files **by calendar week**.
It simply takes all the files it gets from the bash:

```
foreach my $input (@ARGV){
   ...
}
```

The naming convention looks as follows:

```
FILE_XYZ_20140908_0000.000XYZ
```

For the first week of the month it's no problem..

```
FILE_XYZ_2014090[1-7]_*
```

..will match just fine. It's getting tricky when the day switches from 09 to 10.
Is there a pattern that will match all files from 201409 **08**  till 201409 **14**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about older versions of Bash, but in mine (4.1.11(2))

```
echo 9{08..14}
```

returns

```
908 909 910 911 912 913 914
```

In older versions, you have to use a more complex expression (tested in 3.00.15(1)):

```
echo 9{0{8..9},1{0..4}}
```

Comment: The second one worked for me. (3.00.16(1))
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you enable extended pattern support with

```
shopt -s extglob
```

you could specify the following patterns:

```
FILE_XYZ_201409@(01|02|03|04|05|06|07)_*
FILE_XYZ_201409@(08|09|10|11|12|13|14)_*
FILE_XYZ_201409@(15|16|17|18|19|20|21)_*
FILE_XYZ_201409@(22|23|24|25|26|27|28)_*
```

Patterns don't really work well with ranges, which is why you need to write them out explicitly.

Comment: chep, are you expanding these for readability?  Why not just use `0[1-7]_*`, `@(0[8-9]|1[0-4])_*`, etc?

Comment: Yes, readability. The collapsed pattern for the 8-14 range, for example, is only 7 characters shorter, and considerably less clear.